# How to read parameter in mule esb

Tags: java, mule, mule-el, mule-component, mule-module-jpa

I am sending some parameter to mule which is listening through http inbound in 8081 I am sending.

```
http://localhost:8081/hey?age=manoj
```

But I don't know How can I take this as from message??
I know I can access it from message and payload but when I try to do this

```
#[message payload: ['age']]
```

I am getting error that payload is a String type and I am very much confuse in mule.
I want age value.

Comment: COuld you share the actual error message?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Mule 3.6 version or above, the expression has been changed ..
So now, you need the following expression to get the value :-

```
#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.age]
```

You can find the reference here for you query :-
https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/HTTP+Listener+Connector

Comment: Worked in mule 3.7

Answer (score 1):

This will come in as an inbound property.  You can access it using MEL:

```
<logger message="#[message.inboundProperties['age']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Be careful though you need to make sure to use the inboundProperty in the same flow as your HTTP Inbound endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the HTTP query parameters through the inbound property **http.query.params**. To obtain the age parameter, use the following MEL expression

```
#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.get('age')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Mule HTTP Body to Param Map transformer, to convert the Params to a Map.

```
<http:body-to-parameter-map-transformer />
```

Then inorder to access the parameter the MEL expression to be used is #[payload['age']]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Mule 3.6 or 3.7, if you been using the *Body to Parameter* transformer in your mule applications, this has been deprecated. If you need to access the inbound properties values, you can do that using `message.inboundProperties`.

```
#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params']
```

Example:

```
 <set-payload value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it in a groovy script please refer to this

[getting inbound properties of ESB Mule message using Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231587/getting-inbound-properties-of-esb-mule-message-using-groovy)

which basically tells you can use it as

```
message.getInboundProperty('http.query.params')?.yourFantasticParam
```

or

```
message.getInboundProperty('http.query.params')?.age
```