# getting inbound properties of ESB Mule message using Groovy

Tags: groovy, mule, esb

I have groovy transformer component which is to get the inbound properties and set it in the flow vars as like below.

```
if(message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.Brand != null){
    flowVars ['Brand'] = message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.Brand
}
return payload;
```

But I am getting below specified error. It seems inboundProperties are not in the scope of groovy.  Can you please tell me how to access inbound properties in groovy.

Note : I dont want to alter the payload. My aim is to create the flowVars based on queryparms.

Part of Error :

```
No such property: inboundProperties for class: org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage (groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException)
  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter:51 (null)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see a `getInboundProperties()` method [on `DefaultMuleMessage`](https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.3.0/apidocs/org/mule/DefaultMuleMessage.html)

I'm guessing you want:

```
if(message.getInboundProperty('http.query.params')?.Brand){
    flowVars ['Brand'] = message.getInboundProperty('http.query.params').Brand
}
```

Comment: The ? to check null is new syntax for me. Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to set the variable from inbound properties:

1. Replace the groovy component with MEL, replace `<scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">` with `<expression-component doc:name="Expression">`
2. Keep using groovy component, then modify the existing code

   ```
   if(message.getInboundProperty('http.query.params').get('Brand') != null) {
   flowVars ['Brand'] = message.getInboundProperty('http.query.params').get('Brand');
   }
   return payload;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Use message.getInboundProperty.

```
def brand = message.getInboundProperty('http.query.params').Brand
if (brand != null){
    flowVars ['Brand'] = brand
}
return payload;
```

Comment: That will give you a NPE if getInboundProperty returns null